# How to create a background service in Android that actually runs after the app is closed?

Tags: android, service, background

I am trying to write an App for Android, something that will receive messages not through FCM and will work similar to WhatsApp or Telegram etc. That simple!

Although not relevant to the question, I am amazed and frustrated of how bad the documentation and generally the Android OS is, where every version everything deprecated, should not be used because of security holes, and at most the lack of working up-to-date examples. This is in great contrast to javascript, vue, react, node etc. Framework vs. OS, but working with Windows OS was also a good experience.

I looked and I looked and I tried and came up with nothing! This is definitely not a duplicate question, unless something is hidden out there.

Enough bashing and back to the problem:

- I tried context.startService but to no avail.
- I tried stating a different process name in the manifest for my service. The same.
- I tried restarting it when onTaskRemoved was called with sendBroadcast / AlarmManager. It didn't work.
  Same with onDestroy from main Activity. But when doing both, it did work, but was killed by the OS after 1 minute... yes...
- I don't want my recurring task to run every 15 Minutes (WorkerManager)
- Nor JobSchedular (which apparently is insecure, has memory leaks, and other problems. yes...)

Running the Service in the foreground, does seem to work, but then I have the icon (another frustrating issue for itself) of the App. This is expected behavior according to the documentation. Fine. But how do all the other Apps do it without showing their icon in the notification toolbar? Another Android hack?

**Q:** How do I start a Thread, Handler, whatever, that will run forever???

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
...
<application ...>
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart" android:exported="true" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<!-- Already tried with android:exported="true" -->
<service android:name=".PullService" android:exported="false"/>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop">
...
</activity>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```kt
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  ...
  startService(Intent(this, PullService::class.java))
}
```

**PullService.kt**

```kt
override fun onCreate() {
  super.onCreate()
  ...  
  Thread {...}.start()
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
  // seem to work
  startForeground(1, NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).build())
  return START_NOT_STICKY
  
  // return START_STICKY - does not work
}
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
  return null
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "How do start a Thread, Handler, whatever, that will run forever?" -- you don't. That has not been supported in quite some time. "something that will receive messages not through FCM and will work similar to WhatsApp or Telegram etc." -- WhatsApp and Telegram use FCM when on Google Play environments, most likely. What makes you think that they do not? "But how do all the other Apps do it without showing their icon in the notification toolbar?" -- they use FCM.

Comment: Thanks. Fair enough. But why not update the docs, and say that unless it's a foreground service, all related processes and thread will abruptly be destroyed with the main Activity? And not like stated in:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startService(android.content.Intent) 
Last updated 2023-06-27 UTC (and you say it has been like this for years)